# JavaScript and why capital letters sometimes work and sometimes don't

Tags: javascript, html, dom, case-sensitive

In Notepad++, I was writing a JavaScript file and something didn't work: an alert had to be shown when a button was clicked, but it wasn't working.

I has used the auto-complete plugin provided with Notepad++, which presented me with `onClick`.

When I changed the capital `C` to a small `c`, it did work.

So first of all, when looking at the functions in the auto-completion, I noticed a lot of functions using capitals.

But when you change `getElementById` to `getelementbyid`, you also get an error, and to make matters worse, my handbook from school writes all the stuff with capital letters but the solutions are all done in small letters.

So what is it with JavaScript and its selective nature towards which functions can have capital letters in them and which can't?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Javascript is **ALWAYS** case-sensitive, html is not.

It sounds as thought you are talking about whether html attributes (e.g. onclick) are or are not case-sensitive.  The answer is that the attributes are not case sensitive, but the way that we access them through the DOM is. 
So, you can do this:

```
<div id='divYo' onClick="alert('yo!');">Say Yo</div> // Upper-case 'C'
```

or:

```
<div id='divYo' onclick="alert('yo!');">Say Yo</div> // Lower-case 'C'
```

but through the DOM you must use the correct case. So this works:

```
getElementById('divYo').onclick = function() { alert('yo!'); }; // Lower-case 'C'
```

but you cannot do this:

```
getElementById('divYo').onClick = function() { alert('yo!'); }; // Upper-case 'C'
```

EDIT: CMS makes a great point that most DOM methods and properties are in [camelCase](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=45213).  The one exception that comes to mind are event handler properties and these are generally accepted to be [the wrong way to attach to events](http://javascript.about.com/library/blonclick.htm) anyway. Prefer using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) as in:

```
document.getElementById('divYo').addEventListener('click', modifyText, false);
```

Comment: Might be good to explicitly mention that attributes and properties aren't strictly related. An input's value attribute only specifies what it should be when initialized, whereas the input property has the current value. data-* attributes are linked to elem.dataset[*], but unlike the value attribute, dataset is kept in sync both ways (when set on the javascript side, the attribute is set to whatever the toString method returns). Some things like the checked attribute may reflect the respective property, which is needed for css to style things correctly.

Answer (score 6):

A few objects is IE aren't always case-sensitive, including some/most/all ActiveX -- why both **XHR.onReadyStateChange** and **XHR.onreadystatechange** would work fine in IE5 or IE6, but only the latter would work with the native **XMLHttpRequest** object in IE7, FF, etc.

But, a quick reference for "*standard*" API casing:

- **UPPERCASE** - Constants (generally symbolic, since **const** isn't globally supported)
- **Capitalized** - Classes/Object functions
- **lowercase** - Events
- **camelCase** - everything else

No 100% guarantees. But, majority-wise, this is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript API methods are almost all called with [lowerCamelCase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LowerCamelCase) names, and JavaScript is case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Javascript *should* always be case sensitive, but I've seen cases in Internet Explorer where it tolerates all upper case for some function names but not others. I think it is limited to functions that also exist in Visual Basic, as there is some odd inbreeding between the interpreters. Clearly this behavior should be avoided, unless of course your intention is to make code that only runs in one browser :)