# Does casing matter when spelling DOM event names?

Tags: events, dom

When specifying a DOM event name in Javascript, does casing matter? For example, which of the following will work reliably:

1. onMouseOver
2. onmouseover
3. Both are ok. Casing does not matter.
4. It's more complicated than that....

Answer (score 2):

It depends. It is case sensitive in XHTML. Plus, Javascript is *always* case sensitive.

Seems to be a 
[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87934/javascript-and-why-capital-letters-sometimes-work-and-sometimes-dont).