# JS Set onClick action to a Button that was create inside a loop

Tags: javascript, html, generated

How to define the onClick property of the Buttons created inside this loop?.JQuery doesn't seem to work at all for that class.

```
    for(started somewhrere...

        var button = document.createElement('button')
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        var img = document.createElement('img')
            img.src = "../img/download.png"
        var p = document.createElement('p')
            p.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Descargar"))

        div.appendChild(img);
        div.appendChild(p);
        button.appendChild(div);

        button.onClick = "DOSOMETHINGFFS()"

        button.className = "download"

     for end somewhere...}
```

---

```
function DOSOMETHINGFFS(){
    alert("no")
}
```

BTW JQuery isn't really helping at all

```
$(".download").click(function() {
    alert("ok")
});
```

Comment: have you tried `button.onClick = DOSOMETHINGFFS`?

Comment: You're looking for [**onclick**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/87958/2341603) rather than `onClick`.

Comment: shouldn't it be div.appendChild(button);

Comment: you may want a [delegated event](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) e.g. `$.on('click', ".download", function() {
    alert("ok")
});`

Comment: Tried both and the alert refuses to appear. Nope, theres another div that contains the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you're actually adding the elements to the page (e.g. `container.appendChild` below), and you misspelled `onclick`. (You had a capital C.) Otherwise, I think what you did was okay, but it's better to assign the actual function instead of a string with JavaScript code that makes a function call:

```js
function doSomething(url){
    console.log("download " + url);
}

var container = document.getElementById("container");
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.innerText = "click me";
    button.className = "download";
    button.onclick = (function (url) {
        return function () {
            doSomething(url);
        };
    })("URL #" + i);
    container.appendChild(button);
}

$('.download').click(function () {
    console.log("clicked from jQuery handler");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**EDIT**

Also used jQuery to add a handler. That works fine too.

**EDIT 2**

Changed the `onclick` example to include a different parameter for each button. There are several ways to achieve this, but I used an [immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression).

Comment: How to do it with a parameter?

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Each download button fires the download function, and each button should download a specific file. Whenever i tried to pass a parameter (the link or url) it instally downloads onLoad and never triggers. I guess it was called while the loop was running.

Comment: It wasn't that obvious. Thanks for all this help.

Answer (score 1):

This will handle the click events of any element added dynamically to the dom.

```
$('body').on("click",".download" , function() {
    alert("ok");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".download").click(function() {
    alert("ok")
});
```

The above code will work in case the button has been already in the DOM , since you are creating it dynamically so you need to bind the click on the parent element as

```
$(document).on('click','.download',function(){
  alert('ok');
});
```